# Socket IO: How to define disconnected socket id (when multiple tabs)?

Tags: javascript, websocket, server, socket.io

When I open multiple tabs (1, 2, 3), I see in server logs that sockets contains all of this particulars sockets.
I also save this sockets ids in my array.
When I close tab 1,  this socket.id removed from sockets list.
But in my array, it removed only last opened socket. But I need remove 1.

```js
const array = [];
io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
  array.push(socket.id);

  //after opened 3 tabs, there be [socketId-1, socketId-2, socketId-3]

  //then I closing 1st tab and waiting for result [socketId-2, socketId-3]

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      array = array.filter(() => socketId !== socket.id)
      
      //there will be removed socket.id of last connected tab
      console.log(array) // [socketId-1, socketId-2] 
  })
})
```

If I'll can to define socked.id of closed tab, then it resolve my problem. But how to define it inside of socket.on('disconnect')?

Comment: So it sounds like you want to track old connections. Is that right?

Comment: https://love2dev.com/blog/javascript-remove-from-array/#:~:text=You%20can%20remove%20elements%20from,way%20to%20remove%20unwanted%20elements.

Comment: @SHenry Yes. I need disconnected socket.id, since I collect them in other collection, and it should be removed there also.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found solution. May be not best, but it works for me.
In disconnect function I getting all currently connected sockets, then compare with my array and filter them . Probably be better write own filter function, but I used Underscore "intersection" method.

I guess it could behave on performance for apps with a big numbers of online users. But it have right on life)

```js
import _ from 'lodash';

const array = [];

io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
  array.push(socket.id);

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    const connectedSockets = Object.keys(socket.nsp.sockets);

    array = _.intersection(array, connectedSockets);   
  });
})
```